# How to use spring security3.0.3 to secure such business logic?

Tags: spring-security

I have such a requirement. There is a main business object,user a and user b, and administrator. User a or b can create/update/delete their own business object. And user a can't modify user b's business object. Administrator can do every thing. And the business object has a status, in some status, even the owner user can't modify it. I want to secure this by spring security.But it seems can achieve it just by role based security. I feel I need to use spring voter,but I don't know how to configure. Can anybody provide some code  snip or give me suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 3 supports `@PreAuthorize` annotation that allows you to express authorization logic in [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07.html), like this:

```
public class BusinessService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR') or " + 
        "(#o.status != 'someStatus' and hasRole('USER') and #o.ownerName == principal.name)")
    public void updateBusinessObject(BusinessObject o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And you need `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` to apply security aspect.

If the expression is too complex to represent in Spring Expression Language, you can move some logic to Java code by adding custom variables into expression's [`EvaluationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/EvaluationContext.html) (by customizing [`MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html)).

Note, however, that you need to have your code compiled in debug mode in order to use method arguments in the expression.

**See also:**

- [15.3.1 @Pre and @Post Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations)

Comment: Thanks,that would be great.But I used this @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or (#task.status < 3 and hasRole('ROLE_USER'))").It didn't work. I log in as owner of the task,the task's status==3,but I can still upate this task

Comment: @Tom: Make sure that security aspect is properly applied.

Comment: @Tom: Also note that since this approach uses Spring AOP, it works only for calls from outside of your class.

Comment: I use this to secure my update method: @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#task, write) or hasPermission(#task, admin)") . Add When I create task,using the following code to create ace:acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.DELETE, new GrantedAuthoritySid("ROLE_ADMIN"), true);
  acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION, new GrantedAuthoritySid("ROLE_ADMIN"), true);
  acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), BasePermission.WRITE, new GrantedAuthoritySid("ROLE_ADMIN"), true); But even I log in as admin user,I still can't update task.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I'm not familiar with ACL support.